# How can a method in C# be used in XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a method creating a cone, such as in the following code snippet.

Could you explain me how this cone created by CreateCone(...) can be used in a XAML file in the same solution.

C# Code snippet :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public Window()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      CreateCone(new Point3D(0, 0, 0), 0, 0.025, 0.1, 100, Colors.Red);         

     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends when/where you want the method fired.   You could call the method from a Grid event, etc.  Not really sure why you would want to do that though.

Ie.  `<Grid Loaded="CreateConeWrapper" />`, and the wrapper would call the CreateCone() function.

Comment: Well if you had a button that said "Create Cone" you could have this as the `MouseClick` event handler.

Comment: Absolutely.  My Grid event was purely an example of an event on a control, happened to be the first that popped into my head.  Mouseclick is a much more common one for sure!

Answer (score 1):

If you give XAML objects a name like this:

```
<canvas name="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Then you can access them from the code behind file using that name. Depending on the type of control it is you can usually either set the `Content` property, or add stuff to the controls `Children` collection:

```
myCanvas.Children.Add(mycreatedCode);
```